# Elasticsearch part of string multi_match bool

Tags: elasticsearch

I just duplicated mu customer database into Elasticsearch for faster result.

On my listing page I have a search field to search any string into my customer db. the search should be able to match a result on email, first name, last name, id and phone.

I created an `nGram` filter to be able to match only parts of query

```
ES.client.indices.putSettings({
            index: `customer`,
            body: {
                analysis : {
                    index_analyzer: {
                        my_index_analyzer: {
                            type: "custom",
                            tokenizer: "standard",
                            filter: ["lowercase", "mynGram"]
                        }
                      },
                      search_analyzer: {
                        my_search_analyzer: {
                            type: "custom",
                            tokenizer: "standard",
                            filter: [ "standard", "lowercase", "mynGram"]
                        }
                      },
                      filter: {
                        mynGram: {
                            type: "nGram",
                            min_gram: 2,
                            max_gram: 30
                        }
                      }
                },
                max_ngram_diff: 30
            }
        })
```

and my query is

```
{
   "index":"customer",
   "pageNum":1,
   "perPage":20,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "bool":{
                  "should":[
                     {
                        "match":{
                           "organizationId":"org_1"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match":{
                           "organizationId":"org_2"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "multi_match":{
                  "fields":[
                     "id",
                     "email",
                     "firstName",
                     "lastName",
                     "phone"
                  ],
                  "query":"loc"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "sort":{
      "createdAt":{
         "order":"desc"
      }
   }
}
```

But this is not working as I want.

For example one of my emails is `test@geo.loc` and if I search for `loc` I have no result.

I made another test with 4 emails `test@geo.loc` `test1@test.com` `test2@test.com` `test@test.com`. Looking for `test` it only returns `test@geo.loc` and `test@test.com` should return all the results

Other test one of the phones number is `2211111111` if I am looking for `1111` I have no result but `2211111111` works

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **multi_match** try **query_string**

```
 {
       "index":"customer",
       "pageNum":1,
       "perPage":20,
       "query":{
          "bool":{
             "must":[
                {
                   "bool":{
                      "should":[
                         {
                            "match":{
                               "organizationId":"org_1"
                            }
                         },
                         {
                            "match":{
                               "organizationId":"org_2"
                            }
                         }
                      ]
                   }
                },
              {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "*1111*",
                "fields":["id", "email", "firstName", "lastName", "phone"]
              }
            }

       },
       "sort":{
          "createdAt":{
             "order":"desc"
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: It works but I read that it was a bad practice if a lot of documents